# Html.fromHtml() with custom ImageGetter inside ListView recycle issues

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have to show some HTML with images from the internet in a `ListView`. The images are handled in a custom `Html.ImageGetter`. The problem is, I need the `TextView` available to download the images to inside. This leads to having to incorporate the HTML parsing inside the `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView` method. But that method gets called very often by the Android system as it recycles and redraws elements.

How can I stop this recycling from happening? I assume I have to use a different flow. This is my current `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView view = new TextView(context);
    CharSequence element = getItem(position);
    CharSequence html = Html.fromHtml(element.toString(), new MessageImageGetter(context, view), null);
    view.setText(html);

    view.setPadding(12, 4, 12, 4);

    return view;
}
```

Maybe a list-like behavior is possible without the use of `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`, that doesn't recycle and redraw often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I stop this recycling from happening?

You don't. You create a richer model object. Rather than having what appears to be a `ListAdapter<String>`, have a `ListAdapter<Thing>`, where:

- `Thing` holds your existing string value (`element`)
- `Thing` caches the `Html.fromHtml()` result
- Your `getView()` gets the `html` `CharSequence` from the `Thing` and therefore can take advantage of caching

Feel free to substitute a more applicable noun than `Thing`, of course... :-)

Comment: Is it acceptable to make this `Thing` a TextView? The `Html.fromHtml()` *requires* the TextView to be available to download the images into, so I need it available.

Comment: @tolgap: "Is it acceptable to make this Thing a TextView?" -- no. Widgets are expensive; the goal of `ListView` and `ListAdapter` is to recycle them as part of `getView()` processing. "The Html.fromHtml() requires the TextView to be available to download the images into, so I need it available" -- `Html.fromHtml()` has nothing to do with a `TextView`. It creates a `Spannable`. You happen to be putting it in the `TextView`. `Drawables` returned by an `ImageGetter` are put into the `Spannable` itself. The `TextView` only gets involved at rendering time.

Comment: If I don't incorporate the `TextView` in the `ImageGetter`, I can't invalidate the `TextView` to display the `Drawable` once it's done downloading. This results in `Drawables` not being shown until another item gets added to the list, or I start scrolling.

Comment: @tolgap: The `Drawable` is supposed to be downloaded before you call `fromHtml()`, as the `Drawable` needs to be returned by the `ImageGetter`. That all occurs before `fromHtml()` returns, let alone putting the `Spannable` into the `TextView`. If you are trying to do your own asynchronous stuff here, replacing some placeholder `Drawable` with another one via replacing `ImageSpan` elements, you'll need to do what libraries like Picasso, Universal Image Loader, etc. do and take row recycling into account.

Comment: I will look into the suggestions, but your answer about recycling is correct.